# Paste together columns of comma seperated .txt files

Tags: r, paste

I have many .txt files that typically have 5 columns, but some rows have more, for example:

```
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
a,b,c,d,e
```

All I want to do is paste together all columns that extend further than the fifth column. The example above should result in:

```
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e f g
a,b,c,d,e
```

How could I program this in R?

Comment: Are you doing this straight from file or have you already read the data?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, I didn't know that! Your answer was very helpful and you were right to assume I had my data in R already via the "read.csv" function, that I knew "from" beforehand, and that I didn't know what I was doing on stack overflow! :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you have already read your ".csv" file into R, via:

```
dat <- read.csv(file, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
```

---

A little test on your provided data:

```
x <- "a,b,c,d,e
      a,b,c,d,e
      a,b,c,d,e
      a,b,c,d,e,f,g
      a,b,c,d,e"

dat <- read.csv(text = x, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)

#           V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#1           a  b  c  d  e      
#2           a  b  c  d  e      
#3           a  b  c  d  e      
#4           a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#5           a  b  c  d  e
```

---

This maybe another possibility?

```
from <- 5
dat[, from] <- do.call(paste, dat[from:ncol(dat)])  ## merge and overwrite
dat[, (from+1):ncol(dat)] <- NULL  ## drop

#           V1 V2 V3 V4    V5
#1           a  b  c  d   e  
#2           a  b  c  d   e  
#3           a  b  c  d   e  
#4           a  b  c  d e f g
#5           a  b  c  d   e
```

---

My simple approach requires you know `from` beforehand; but it seems you do know it.

Answer (score 3):

We can read the dataset using `readLines`, split the 'lines' by ',' into a `list`, find the minimum of the `length` of the `list` ('minLength'), create a logical condition ('i1'), subset the 'lst' and `paste` the elements that are greater than the 'minLength' together and use `ifelse` to create a vector.

```
lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt")
lst <- strsplit(lines, ",")
minLength <- min(lengths(lst))
i1 <- lengths(lst) > minLength
v1 <- sapply(lst[i1], function(x) paste(x[(minLength+1):length(x)], collapse=" "))
v2 <- ifelse(i1, v1, "")
```

NOTE: This will not need to read the data and check how many columns are there.  It will automatically find the number of valid columns and paste the others.

After we create the vector ('v2'), we can read the 'lines' with `read.csv` and `fill = TRUE`

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = lines, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
df1$newCol <- v2
```

---

Or we can directly read the file with  `read.csv` and find the column which will have the first NA or "" value.  When there are 100s of columns with 1000s of lines, it becomes difficult to check where the first NA or `""` starts (assuming that there are no other NA or `""` in the dataset)

```
 df1 <- read.csv("yourfile.txt", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
 i1 <-  which.max(colSums(dat=="")!=0) 
 #i1 <- which.max(colSums(is.na(dat))!=0) #if it is NA
 transform(df1[seq(i1-1)], newCol= do.call(paste, df1[i1:ncol(df1)]))
 #       V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 newCol
 #1       a  b  c  d  e       
 #2       a  b  c  d  e       
 #3       a  b  c  d  e       
 #4       a  b  c  d  e    f g
 #5       a  b  c  d  e
```

NOTE: When I posted first, I used `do.call(paste`

---

Yet another approach would be using `count.fields`

```
i1 <- min(count.fields("yourfile.txt", sep=","))
```

then read the dataset using `read.csv/read.table` and `transform` the data as in the above approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a unix-based system, you could just pre-process the file before 
loading it into R (example file `ff.txt`):

```
$ paste  -d ',' <(cut -f 1-4 -d ',' ff.txt) <(cut -f 5- -d ',' ff.txt | tr ',' ' ') > ff-mod.txt
```

which writes a new file `ff-mod.txt`:

```
$ cat ff-mod.txt 
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e f g
a,b,c,d,e
```

The file can the easily be read into R:

```
> read.table('ff-mod.txt', sep=',')
  V1 V2 V3 V4    V5
1  a  b  c  d     e
2  a  b  c  d     e
3  a  b  c  d     e
4  a  b  c  d e f g
5  a  b  c  d     e
```